# Graph in logarithmic scale for ordinates for the Jacobi method

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have to program the Jacobi, Gauss Seidel and SOR methods to resolve Ax=b. We use a decomposition A=M-N.

For the Jacobi method, for example, we use M=diag(A) and N=M-A.

I programmed a function

```
jacobi(A,b,Imax,err,x0)
```

with the matrix A, the column vector b, a maximum number of iterations Imax, a tolerance err, for the Jacobi method. I used a "stop test" [image] where [image] is  the "residual" at the step k.

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

def jacobi(A,b,Imax,eps,x0):
    M=np.diag(np.diag(A))
    N=M-A
    r=np.dot(A,x0)-b
    x=x0
    i=0
    err=1+eps
    res=[]
    while ((i<Imax) and ((la.norm(r))>=eps)):
        x=np.dot(np.dot((la.inv(M)),N),x)+np.dot((la.inv(M)),b)
        r=np.dot(A,x)-b
        err = la.norm(r,2)
        res.append(err)
        i=i+1
    return (x,i,res)
```

and the test :

```
A=np.array([[2,0,0],[4,5.4,0],[7,8,9]])
x0=np.array([[1],[1],[1]])   
b=np.array([[20],[8],[7]])
print(jacobi(A,b,1000,10**(-3),x0))
```

Now, I have to represent on a graph (in logarithmic scale for ordinates) the values [image] in function of n.

I just would like to know how to represent a graph in logarithmic scal ? I'm beginner in Python and I don't know how to represent a graph... I tried to be clear, sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a log plot for some dummy values

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

j = np.power(10,range(10))    # <--- here use your computed values instead

plt.plot(j)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image: log plot]

If you want log-log set the `xscale` as well.